# How to get three circle dot on my web page?

Tags: html, css, web, fonts

I use  `...` but dots become squares, when i increase their size. I want get circle dots.

How to do it?

Comment: you have a try source code? please share here code

Comment: What font are you using?

Comment: Change your font? [**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/Ruddy/emjfF/)  - See dots. And now font change - Not dots. [**DEMO HERE**](http://jsfiddle.net/Ruddy/emjfF/1/)

Comment: @Ruddy funniest answer ever :D

Comment: @Mr.Alien You love it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It mainly depends on the font you're using. You can try changing it or maybe use some special characters :

Bull x 3 (`&bull;`) = •••

Ellipsis (`&hellip;`) = …

(the result visible here is not representative of what you'll get with a zoom or a bigger font size.)

Answer (score 2):

We have **dots**! :)

### CSS:

```
body {
    font-size: 400px;
}
```

[**DEMO HERE**](http://jsfiddle.net/Ruddy/emjfF/)

And now we have **squares**! :(

### CSS:

```
body {
    font-size: 400px;
    font-family: Impact, Charcoal, sans-serif;
}
```

[**DEMO HERE**](http://jsfiddle.net/Ruddy/emjfF/1/)

Without seeing code its hard to tell but it is most probably the font you have.

Answer (score 0):

you have to use font-family:"Trebuchet MS", Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;

Answer (score 0):

I get the feeling from the way you've asked the question that you're using this purely for design purposes, in which case you should not be using punctuation at all. So in the interest of going completely overboard unnecessarily, here's an accessible version:

HTML:

```
<div
    class="dots"
    aria-description="Three Dots">        
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.dots {
    white-space: nowrap;
}
.dots, .dots:before, .dots:after {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
    background: black;
    border-radius: 50%;
}

.dots:before, .dots:after {
    content: ' ';
}

.dots:before {
    margin-left: 24px;
}
```

Answer (score -2):

**Its a font issue. Try to change the font**

Comment: Oh dear. `And here in the wild, we have a human that has yet to conquer the skills of reading.`